# asort using the second element

Tags: php, sorting, asort

Starting with this array :

```
$TEST=array (
    0 => array ( 0 => 'b', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'O', ),
    1 => array ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'z', 2 => 'O', ),
    2 => array ( 0 => 'c', 1 => 'x', 2 => 'O', ),
)
```

How to sort it to have ? (xyz based on second element) :

```
$TEST=array (
    2 => array ( 0 => 'c', 1 => 'x', 2 => 'O', ),
    0 => array ( 0 => 'b', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'O', ),
    1 => array ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'z', 2 => 'O', ),
)
```

The result of a simple `asort($TEST)` is (abc based on first element) :

```
$TEST=array (
    1 => array ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'z', 2 => 'O', ),
    0 => array ( 0 => 'b', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'O', ),
    2 => array ( 0 => 'c', 1 => 'x', 2 => 'O', ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with this one line of code:

```php
array_multisort( array_column($yourArray, $index), SORT_ASC, $yourArray );
```

In your case, this is how to use it:

```php
$TEST=array (
    0 => array ( 0 => 'b', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'O', ),
    1 => array ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'z', 2 => 'O', ),
    2 => array ( 0 => 'c', 1 => 'x', 2 => 'O', ),
)
array_multisort( array_column($TEST, 1), SORT_ASC, $TEST );
print_r($TEST);
```

Check array_multisort here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @bobdylan Note that this changes the keys of the array...

Answer (score 0):

An explicit uasort with a spaceship:

```
<?php

$items = [
    0 => [ 0 => 'b', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'O' ],
    2 => [ 0 => 'c', 1 => 'x', 2 => 'O' ],
    1 => [ 0 => 'a', 1 => 'z', 2 => 'O' ]
];

uasort($items, function($a, $b) { return $a[1] <=> $b[1]; });
var_export($items);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'c',
    1 => 'x',
    2 => 'O',
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'b',
    1 => 'y',
    2 => 'O',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'z',
    2 => 'O',
  ),
)
```

Written in short arrow function notation:

```
uasort($items, fn($a, $b) => $a[1] <=> $b[1]);
```